# How do I resolve the error on hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

While trying to follow tutorial on building your first network I've got following output:

```
$  ./byfn.sh -m generate
```

> Generating certs and genesis block for with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10000'
>   Continue (y/n)? y
>   proceeding ...
>   which: no cryptogen in (/c/users/ayush/fabric-samples/first-network/../bin:/c/users/ayush/fabric-samples/first-network:c:/users/ayush/bin:/c/Users/ayush/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox:/c/Users/ayush/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/ayush/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cmd:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Gradle/gradle-3.3/bin:/c/Go/bin:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Users/ayush/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts:/c/Users/ayush/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36:/c/Users/ayush/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/python:/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox:/c/Users/ayush/AppData/Roaming/npm:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
>   cryptogen tool not found. exiting

What is the problem and how can I get it solved?

Answer (score 10):

The key of you problem is in the last sentence:

> cryptogen tool not found. exiting

You need to make sure to have `cryptogen` tool compiled prior to trying run the example with `./byfn.sh`. Just run from fabric home folder:

```
make cryptogen configtxgen peer orderer peer-docker orderer-docker tools-docker
```

---

**Update**

You are missing: "[Platform specific binaries](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html)", see here how to get them.

Comment: I followed this but it said `make: *** No rule to make target 'cryptogen'.  Stop.`

Comment: you need to obtain binaries, posted a link within answer on doc which explains how to do it.

Comment: See update, you need to obtain platform specific binaries.

Comment: Can you add detail on your setup?

Comment: Adding Platform specific binaries and linking them to $PATH solved an issue for me.

Comment: The link you posted is dead @ArtemBarger

Comment: Updated new location.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a mac, do the following in terminal:

```
brew tap hyperledger/fabric

brew install fabric-tools
```

and then try again with `./byfn.sh -m generate command`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me after the platform specific binaries answers did not.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer now.
This issue is caused by the lack of cryptogen, which is indeed a command tool. The simplest way to get it is to download the platform specific binaries into your local machine, 
  here is the sh:

```
cd fabric-samples
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.1.sh | bash
```

This sh will download a bash file which would pull the latest Fabric docker images and the platform specific tools, its content is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

export VERSION=1.0.1
export ARCH=$(echo "$(uname -s|tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'|sed 's/mingw64_nt.*/windows/')-$(uname -m | sed 's/x86_64/amd64/g')" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
#Set MARCH variable i.e ppc64le,s390x,x86_64,i386
MARCH=`uname -m`

dockerFabricPull() {
  local FABRIC_TAG=$1
  for IMAGES in peer orderer couchdb ccenv javaenv kafka zookeeper tools; do
      echo "==> FABRIC IMAGE: $IMAGES"
      echo
      docker pull hyperledger/fabric-$IMAGES:$FABRIC_TAG
      docker tag hyperledger/fabric-$IMAGES:$FABRIC_TAG hyperledger/fabric-$IMAGES
  done
}

dockerCaPull() {
      local CA_TAG=$1
      echo "==> FABRIC CA IMAGE"
      echo
      docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ca:$CA_TAG
      docker tag hyperledger/fabric-ca:$CA_TAG hyperledger/fabric-ca
}

: ${CA_TAG:="$MARCH-$VERSION"}
: ${FABRIC_TAG:="$MARCH-$VERSION"}

echo "===> Downloading platform binaries"
curl https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hyperledger/fabric/hyperledger-fabric/${ARCH}-${VERSION}/hyperledger-fabric-${ARCH}-${VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz

echo "===> Pulling fabric Images"
dockerFabricPull ${FABRIC_TAG}

echo "===> Pulling fabric ca Image"
dockerCaPull ${CA_TAG}
echo
echo "===> List out hyperledger docker images"
docker images | grep hyperledger*
```

Now it is based on Fabric 1.0.1, you can find the latest version of this bash from here :
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html

After the sh execution is completed, there will be a folder named bin in current directory, then copy the files under this folder into a searchable folder, such as

```
cp ./bin/*  $GOROOT/bin
```

Then you can test if the cryptogen exists by type command:

```
which cryptogen
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is in the last line of error which says 
"cryptogen tool not found. exiting"

Please follow below steps to resolve this issue-

1. Download the platform-specific binaries using command

> curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/v1.0.5/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.0.5

Once you run the command it will download various tools like cryptogen, configtxgen etc under bin directory.

2. add the bin directory to your PATH variable using below command

> export PATH=$PATH:[path-to-bin-directory]

now try to build the network again. 
I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below steps to resolve this issue:

1.Download the platform-specific binaries using command

curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0"

Once you run the command it will download various tools like cryptogen, configtxgen etc under bin directory.

1.add the bin directory to your PATH variable using below command
export PATH=./bin:$PATH

Answer (score 2):

Step1: `cd fabric-samples`

Step2:

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/v1.0.5/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.0.5`

Step3: `cd fabric-samples/first-network`

Step4: `./byfn.sh -m generate`

You will see a brief description as to what    will occur, along with a yes/no command line prompt. Respond with a y    or hit the return key to execute the described action.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its still an issue or not.....
You can either try to use what @Artem already mentioned, 
or
you can add the `......fabric-samples/bin` folder to your path, which has the tools. its the same `fabric-samples` folder that has the `byfn.sh`

Answer (score 0):

cryptogen command is under the bin directory where you installed (or uncompressed) the fabric tarball. So you just need to update your $PATH variable so that the shell knows where the cryptogen command can be found.
This code should work:

```
export "$PATH:/<home>/<fabric>/bin"
```

Where `<home>` is your home directory, such as `/home/sindelio`
and `<fabric>` is where the fabric was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you close the terminal, following solution works:

export PATH=$PATH:PATH_TO_FABRIC_SAMPLES/bin

Answer (score 0):

Probably have missed this Step

*Download Platform-specific Binaries*

**https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html**

run command in 
cd Fabric-Samples

Answer (score 0):

Download the platform-specific binaries after cd into your workspace.

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/v1.4.0/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash
```

and **make sure your version of binaries matches your configuration file**.